# Inherited resthight of parent container

Tags: html, css

I get a flexible count of elements out of a database and put them into a list.

There is a container below the list. This container should take the rest height of the parent container.

On the code below you can see my current result. the Div in #rightContent should take the complete rest height. But i dont know how.

Html:

```
<section>
        <aside>
            I'm a sidebar!
        </aside>
        <main>
            <article id="leftContent">
                <img src="http://fs1.directupload.net/images/150422/6x5qv8ik.png">
            </article>
            <article id="rightContent">
                <h1>Headline</h1>
                <hr>
                <ul>
                    <li>list1</li>
                    <li>list2</li>
                    <li>list3</li>
                </ul>
                <div>
                    <p>
                        a lot of text
                    </p>
                </div>
            </article>
        </main>
    </section>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        section {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
        section aside {
            position: fixed;
            right: 50px;
            width: 150px;
            background-color: firebrick;
            color: white;
            padding: 25px;
            height: 100%;
        }
        section main {
            position: relative;
            margin-right: 250px;
            left: 0;
            display: block;
            width: auto;
            border: 1px solid yellow;
        }
        section #leftContent {
            position: relative;
            display: block;
            border: 1px solid green;
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            height: auto;
            width: 50%;
        }
        section #leftContent img {
            width: 100%;
            height: auto;
            display: block;
        }
        section #rightContent {
            position: absolute;
            display: inline-block;
            border: 1px solid blue;
            right: 0;
            margin-left: 50%;
            width: 49%;
            height: 100%;
            top: 0;
        }
        section #rightContent div {
            border: 1px solid violet;
            position: relative;
            margin-bottom: 0;
        }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kzkpLg11/

This image shows what i want.

[image: Websitelayout]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it like this: http://jsfiddle.net/kzkpLg11/1/

Involves a few extra elements but the browser support will be ok. It's basically all about this piece of CSS. But I suggest you have a look at the fiddle.

```
.table {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.row {
    display: table-row;

}
.cell {
    display: table-cell;
}
```

You could also solve this problem with [Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). But that might be a little trickier.